# Algolia stuck on "Algolia Search Products" in "Index Management"

Tags: magento-1.9, algolia

Algolia stuck on "Algolia Search Products" in "Index Management" Its been days I have already deleted all the Indices from Algolia and started with an empty one but no use, When I open magento backend it says "PROCESSING" for "Algolia Search Products" in "Index Management"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to delete all files in your var/locks/ inside your Magento directory?

I believe a .lock file has not been removed properly.

Comment: I already checked that, there is no folder "locks" in the "var" folder.